# Uploading files/creating folder outside webroot with mkdir and fopen over https connection

Tags: php, ssl, permissions, https, fopen

I am working on a web app that allows registered users to upload files to the folders outside the webroot. The basic workflow is as follow:

- user signs up over ssl certificate protecting his/her info
- a folder is created outside the webroot with 777 permissions so that he/she can upload files into that folder
- the user uploads a file
- file is temporarily stored in the script's working folder, converted to a text file, moved into the user's folder outside the webroot and then temporary fileis deleted.

It looks like I can't even create a user's directory outside the webroot, let alone upload files into that directory. I'm using `mkdir` over the ssl connection. I have enabled `allow_url_fopen` and `allow_url_include`, but still no luck. I'm pretty sure openssl is enabled. Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance,
Yulia.

Comment: Some code samples could help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The directory outside the web root in which the new user directories are created must be writable by the web server user, in addition to creating the new user directories as 777.

Supposing the following structure:

```
root
  |->users
  |    |->new user1
  |    |->new user2
  |->www docroot
```

Set ownership on `root/users` to have the group of the web server user and make it writable.  This assumes the directory is already owned by `root`, but if it's on a hosting service change to the existing owner username.  Also assumes `apache` is the web server user.

```
chown root:apache /root/users
chmod 770 /root/users
```

Comment: turns out i can create a folder using mkdir over http connection, but not over https in the directory outside the webroot. however, if the newly created folder is inside httpdocs it doesnt even matter if im using http or https.